how to make group unassigned?
I am trying to model a job assign model for job groups. In the scenario, each group contains several jobs. Each job requires different resource skill to perform.
One requirement is that the jobs in the group should have same assigned status with other job  in the same group.
I tried to implemented the constaints with HARD penalty for each group with inconsistent status as below.
Thanks for any help.
constraintFactory.forEachIncludingNullVars(Allocation.class)
                .groupBy(
                        a -> a.getTask()
                                .getProject()
                                .getId(),
                        ConstraintCollectors.sum(b -> b.isAssigned() ? 1 : 0),
                        ConstraintCollectors.count()
                )
                .filter((project, assigned, size) -> { 

                    return assigned != size && assigned >0;
 
                })
                .penalize(
                        HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                                (project, assigned, act) -> 1
                )
                .asConstraint("projectTasksConsistent");

but the solver yields a result with hard score 1, how to keep all job in the group unassinged while there is insufficent resource to perform any job in the group?
two groups [0,1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8,9]
Task: 0 => 5
Task: 1 => 6
Task: 2 => 7
Task: 3 => 8
Task: 4 => 9
Task: 5 => 0
Task: 6 => 1
Task: 7 => 2
Task: 8 => 3
Task: 9 => null


Adding the hard constraint is straightforward, but it then never does anything with them after the Construction Heuristics.
The fix is to use pillarChange/SwapMoves or even better smart custom moves (which is easier said than done).

Thanks Geoffrey.
While there are other constraints as below:

jobs need to be performed sequentially with in one group, each job should only start if the pre job is done.
each job has different skill requirement, each resource provide only one skill.
resources are devided in group (sevice team) , one job group (like a project) shoud only use the resouces within same group.

Do you have any recommendtion to realize this ?
